# Best autocomplete for huge amount of select options from a 2d array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, multidimensional-array

For fields where are no more than thousand options available drop down lists seem to make the job. However, I have two arrays that flirt around dozens of thousands, so putting them to a comboboxes would be a killer for the browser. My guess is that best would be a simple text input, but with a autocomplete feature. Over the top first went autocomplete from `jQueryUI`, but I've found out it isn't compatible with 2d arrays like:

```
var fkOptionList = [[1, 'Orange'],[2, 'Banana'],[3, 'Coconut']]
```

Since I have my arrays written in this fashion, I'd prefer not to rewrite them. Perhaps you know a workaround for this, or a better way for dealing with such huge amount of options?

Comment: `[1]['Orange']` and other elements in the example array are undefined, making your array `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`

Comment: You should set up an example showing the problem, as I see several issues here. Are your lists stored entirely client side? You should be able to write a custom search handler that can take your data however it is formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant:

```
var fkOptionList = [[1,'Orange'],[2,'Banana'],[3,'Coconut']];
```

You can use a map function (e.g. the [`_.map` routine in underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#map)) to rewrite the 2d array as the necessary 1d array.  There's also a lot of effort put in to ajax-loaded autocompletes, so if it's easier to process into a 1d array on the server side that might be a good option.

Comment: ok, but [how](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655991/2d-array-to-associative-array-using-underscores-map) I'm meant to do it exactly?

Comment: Looks like you discovered, but the method that @Ixe mentioned below is appropriate.  Lodash is an alternate underscore implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Don't be afraid to run it through a `map` or a loop to flatten it.

```
myNewArray = [[1, 'Orange'],[2, 'Banana'],[3, 'Coconut']].map(function(el) {
    return el[1];
});
```

It's a negligible performance hit, especially if you use a functional library such as [lodash](http://lodash.com/);