# 2d array to associative array using underscore's _.map

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, underscore.js

I'm trying to map 2d array:

```
var fkOptionList2d = [[3, 'Orange'],[5, 'Banana'],[6, 'Coconut']]
```

to an associative array:

```
var fkOptionList1d = [{id: 1, label: 'Orange'},{id: 2, label: 'Banana'},{id: 3, label: 'Coconut'}]
```

but I'm new to underscore.js and don't quite get it yet. Should it be something like:

```
fkTableArr1d = _.object(_.map(fkTableArr2d, function(item, id) {
   return [{"id: " + id,"label: " + item}]
}));
```

?

Comment: Have actually you tried running anything? Your final bit of code should give you something close

Comment: good to know :) but I get `Unexpected identifier` near `return`

Comment: It should be `return [{ id: id, label: item }]`; you don't need to construct the object as a string (it's not JSON)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding you need to use

```
return [{
    "id " : id, "label " : item
}]
```

instead of

```
return [{"id: " + id,"label: " + item}]
```

You are returning invalid JSON from the function

Additionally you don't need `_.object` method

```
fkTableArr1d = _.map(fkTableArr2d, function(item, id) {
      return [{
        "id " : id, "label " : item
        }];
    });
```

### [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/W67Zr/2/)

Comment: I've changed it, but console.log shows `Object {[object Object]: undefined} `

Comment: @OverdrivenFall, Can you create a fiddle

Comment: @OverdrivenFall, see demo http://jsfiddle.net/W67Zr/2/. you don't need _.object method. I have also updated answer

Comment: it works, but label becomes an array, according to `console.log(fkTableArr1d[0][0]);` : `Object {id : 0, label : Array[2]}`, shouldn't it be a string?
 `

Comment: ok, I got it, from the 3 of `function(list, iterator, context)` I actually wanted `list[0]` which is ID and `list[1]` - name

Comment: @OverdrivenFall, great :)